# Facebook Graph API - Select a single account

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to select a single account using the graph api ?

I have tried everything I know of:

```
graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/accounts/<page_id>?access_token=<access_token>

graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/accounts?access_token=<access_token>&id=<page_id>
```

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? what do you mean by "selecting an account?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to retrieve the access token for a specific page, using the access token of a user who has granted you `manage_pages` permission?

If so: `https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>?fields=access_token&access_token=<USER_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

Comment: To be fair, it's only mentioned one place in the docs, and most people just iterate over /me/accounts until they find the one they want